How to get every element of a <li> on a <ul> with automatic scroll?
I want to scrap the "people" page of a company on Linkedin. So there is a section that have a list of cards of workers. It is necessary to do automatic scroll to get all the workers. I'm using selenium both for navigation and for scraping. So if there is no connection to the user, it would simply go to the next <li>. If there is a connection, it would click on the link, go to the user's profile, get all the data, save this data on database and go back to the "people" page and go to the next <li>... but in the print that I used as debugger, it just prints the name and position of the first on the list, the first <li> as if I was doing f"ind_element", instead of "find_elements". Also, I guess that there is a chance that the automatic scroll may be wrong, but I don't know what is wrong.
def faz_consulta():
    url = entrada.get()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.save_screenshot('PAGINALINKEDIN.png')
    url_people = url + '/people/' 
    driver.get(url_people)       
    workers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class = 'display-flex list-style-none flex-wrap']//li[@class = 'grid grid__col--lg-8 block org-people-profile-card__profile-card-spacing']")
    for worker in workers:

        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        linkedin_user = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'org-people-profile-card__profile-info']//div[@class = 'ember-view lt-line-clamp lt-line-clamp--single-line org-people-profile-card__profile-title t-black']").text
        print(linkedin_user)
        position_linkedin_user = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'org-people-profile-card__profile-info']//div[@class = 'ember-view lt-line-clamp lt-line-clamp--multi-line']").text
        print(position_linkedin_user                                
        
        if(linkedin_user != "Usuário do LinkedIn"):
            worker_card = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'org-people-profile-card__profile-info']")
            worker_link = funcionario_card.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').click()
            print('user's profile')
            driver.save_screenshot('PERFILLINKEDIN.png')
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            name_worker = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"text-heading-xlarge inline t-24 v-align-middle break-words").text
            position_worker = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "text-body-medium break-words").text
            experiences = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//section[@class = 'artdeco-card pv-profile-card break-words mt2']//ul[@class = 'bYpMhDbGeHrPlJHJoKkUOYvSmZyJIyEvfrLc']//li[@class = 'artdeco-list__item MHGhNRxrFEYePDVElXiPzsGcfCtVjWRE UHceesMDBsAFbVbsOghsJALmURLeFDeg']")
            first_experience = experiences[0]
            experience_position_initial_inicio = primeira_experiencia.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'display-flex flex-column full-width align-self-center']//span[@class = 't-14 t-normal t-black--light'//span[@class = 'pvs-entity__caption-wrapper']").text
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO tbl_Empresa_inkedin_Funcionario (Name, Position, initial_position) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)',( name_worker,  worker_position, experience_position_initial_inicio.split('-')[0]))
            con.commit()
            driver.back()
            previous_page_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
            new_page_height = driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
            if new_page_height == previous_page_height:
                break
            previous_page_height = new_page_height
    

